# Insert NOW() in mysql through a python script

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

Simplified version of my issue which I couldn't find a straight answer for. I need to insert the current datetime into a mysql table:

```
query = "INSERT INTO tickets (ticket_num, ticket_time) VALUES (' " + str(ticket_num) + "', NOW());"
cursor.execute(query)
```

The only thing I notice in the error message is

```
charset = db.character_set_name()
```

The insert statement works fine when I execute it directly in mysql

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand the question.  I'm inferring that if you run the same command in mysql - it works.
What happens if you print out 'query' and run it directly in mysql?
How different is it from your working command?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain that properly. I need to insert the current time into a mysql table. I am writing a python script. I can use the NOW() function in mysql with no problem.

Comment: Note that you have a sneaky space before your ticket_num which will be inserted.

Comment: The spaces are just to differentiate the " and ' on the posting. In the actual script everything is perfect. Now, how can I get the current date and time in this field?

Comment: What library are you using to connect to the database? Also, the way your query is right now you are vulnerable to a [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Rather than appending the query string together, use [bind parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Mitigation) to avoid this.

Comment: MySQLdb, datetime. My application is local to the raspberry pi, but i'll definitely implement your suggestion. I like to do things the correct way.